# Ajax post can't find action controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk, action

I'm writing a simple web app that allows users to login via facebook. When using the javascript sdk, I'm able to retrieve the proper credentials, but my ajax post is unable to find the mvc action to process the information.

Here's the js code:

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var credentials = { uid: response.authResponse.userID, accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken };
                SubmitLogin(credentials);
            }
        });

        function SubmitLogin(credentials) {
            alert("Creds: " + credentials.uid + ":::" + credentials.accessToken);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                ContentType: 'application/json',
                url: '@Url.Action("FacebookLogin","Home")',
                data:JSON.stringify(credentials), 
                success: function () {
                    window.location("~/Views/Account/Home.cshtml");
                },
                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                 }
           });
        }
```

and the corresponding controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FacebookLogin(string uid, string accessToken)
    {
        Session["uid"] = uid;
        Session["accessToken"] = accessToken;

        return null;
    }
```

The model used in the controller:

```
public class FBLoginModel
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
}
```

The alert in the js function shows the correct token, but my ajax post is unable to the action. When I remove the "[HttpPost]" above the controller, I can access the action, but all data I attempt to pass is null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow devised a solution... By writing out the url and adding a forward slash to my ajax call, somehow my ajax call can find my action.

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'Home/FacebookLogin/',
     data: {
         'uid': response.authResponse.userID,
         'accessToken': response.authResponse.accessToken
     },
     cache: false,
     success: function (result) { },
     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
     }
});
```

Comment: url shoud be  url: 'YourAppName/Home/FacebookLogin/', in production version

Answer (score 2):

use

```
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         ContentType: 'application/json',
         url: '@Url.Action("FacebookLogin","Home")',
         data:JSON.stringify(credentials),
         success: function () {
              window.location("~/Views/Account/Home.cshtml");
         },
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
         }
     });
```

Ther should be single quote in 'Url.Action()'

Yout Controller action should be like below.Because you are not passing model items

```
 public JsonResult FacebookLogin(long uid,string accessToken)
    {
    Session["uid"] = uid;
    Session["accessToken"] = accessToken;
    return null; //Because you are not posting anything back
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. For some reason, having [httppost] tied to my action seems to be hiding it from the ajax call.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong, the only error I'm getting back is from the json request which says: "[HttpException]: A public action method 'FacebookLogin' was not found on controller 'MyApp.Controllers.HomeController'

Comment: I still get the same error, however when I remove the [httppost] from above the action, I get no error back. I just have to change my return line to "return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);". Though, doing this does not allow me to post data to my controller. I'm starting think the issue is elsewhere, but this is the only problem I can find.

Comment: With the [Httppost], the error I am getting is:  "Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. "                                             without that [httppost], I can access the action. With that, I cannot access the action.

Comment: give us the updated code of view and controller, and update your question

Comment: Using [httppost] generates the error that says my action does not exist. Not using [httppost] would prevent me from sending data to that controller... or atleast that seems to be the case. I've updated the code

Comment: I now realize that this is a problem of my webhost. My ajax calls work in local version but not on the production version.